# Doctrine 1.2 - How to connect 2 databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, doctrine

I have two databases on my server, I need to connect these two databases using Doctrine 1.2 so I use both as a single database, creating models and everything.

In my bootstrap.php file I have:

```
Doctrine_Manager::connection('mysql://safonizer-user:e41b74468b2c867f06759c5e7255c838@localhost/safonizer','padrao');
Doctrine_Manager::connection('mysql://safonizer-user:e41b74468b2c867f06759c5e7255c838@localhost/padraosaude','padrao1');
```

But does not work the way I want ... someone can help me do this? It has to do this and how?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the Doctrine 1.2 [documentation on connections](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/connections/en)?  That makes two particular comments that you should consider (it's not clear from your *"...does not work the way I want..."* in your original question what problem you are encountering):

1. As per the documentation's "Current Connection" section, note that *"The current connection is the last opened connection."*
2. To change the current connection use `Doctrine_Manager::setCurrentConnection()` (in your case using `padrao` or `pardrao1` as parameters).

If you are interested in queries that span the two databases, you should read the Doctrine 1.2 documentation on [cross database joins](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/cross-database-joins).